# How to wait for completing build of React app in CI pipeline

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have a React app which I want to test with Cypress in my GitLab pipeline. The problem is that the app is pretty big and takes some time to compile and be accessible. So within my pipeline the Cypress tests starts before starting the React server has completed. How can I wait for the React server or detect that it has started before running my Cypress test?

This is my pipeline:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

cypress test:
  stage: test
  image: cypress/browsers:node-20.9.0-chrome-118.0.5993.88-1-ff-118.0.2-edge-118.0.2088.46-1
  script:   
    - npm ci
    - npx update-browserslist-db@latest --yes
    - npm start &
    - npx cypress run --browser chrome
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Configure Cypress To Wait Longer (or Indefinitely) for BaseUrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65358642/how-to-configure-cypress-to-wait-longer-or-indefinitely-for-baseurl)

Comment: Yes, perfect thank you. I think its a little bit misleading that cypress has the above setup on its own docs here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/gitlab-ci and contradics itself on the documentation on how to boot the server that just npm start & cypress run should not be used